# How to debug chrome crash?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, crash, google-chrome-devtools, postmortem-debugging

I have application that crashes chrome tab after some amount of hours, and I want to understand why this is happening.

How can I debug this? and see if this is a memory leak? and if it's a memory leak - can I get the heap view at the time of the crash?